# Backtesting Value at Risk. With kupiec test

Tags: backtesting, value-at-risk

I have a certain problem with backtesting calculated earlier Value at Risk.

I've got calculated daily VaR with historical simulation method for stocks. I've used two values of alpha 0.05 and 0.1. Now, I want to backtest this values with Kupiec test. What alpha should I use for Kupiec test? When I'm using 0.05 alpha for VaR calculated with 0.1, I have to reject null hypothesis for all stocks. Is it normal? Or I should use 0.1 alpha for Kupiec test in this case for comparison between these two models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When backtesting VaR results using Kupiec test you should choose the respective significance levels as your VaRs. Thus, using 0.05 alpha for VaR with 99% confidence level is not correct. From [Dowd](https://books.google.com/books?id=4GhKQT3gjbIC&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=kupiec%20test%20significance&source=bl&ots=ETp4f76mgv&sig=YVsKekXrJUIDXe3XGfAtL5hbYcE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD3fKqprXUAhWqIJoKHSowC-0Q6AEIazAH#v=onepage&q=kupiec%20test%20significance&f=false):

> To implement the Kupiec test, we require data on *n*, *p* and *x*. The
>   first are easily found from the sample size and VaR confidence level,
>   and we can derive *x* from a set of paired observations of P/L and VaR
>   each period.